# Conversion to Dalvik format failed 65536 limit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jaxb

Issue - `Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

This is a new question. I am using eclipse not android studio. I have already read previous questions on stackoverflow and I have tried all sorts of solutions from enabling progaurd, enabling dexjumbo, importing multidex project and jar in eclipse etc. Nothing helped my issue. I am stuck in this issue for 2 days. I have already removed all the unneccessary jar files from libs by trial and error running the app. Now i am left with all thats necessary and still I get the error.

```
What am I trying to do?
```

I am actually trying to read a docx file from internal storage using docx4j on android device. I have made an independent app which works fine. I have tested reading, writing and conversion in independent projects of eclipse but now that I want to integrate my code onto a group project, I get this error. It has 3 more other jar files which are required for other processes. I have removed 8 jars which didn't change the output in independent project and am left with 10.

As per docx4j - "Dalvik  limit of 65536 method references per dex file is more an issue running docx4j on Android than one related to JAXB, but it is worth noting.  We’re running very close to this limit."

Now whats next? I have no other option than to either try Pre-Dexing as per [this article](https://fuzzproductions.com/news/the-mythical-android-method-limit-solved) or remove this 65k limit some how. Please tell me how do I fix this issue for both case. Give me some ideas as I can't remove any more jars.

Link to image of jars I am using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksUxn.png

If anyone can tell me the necessary classes to use instead of jar ae-awt. That will be great.

Comment: See this from official documentation of android: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I have read it already. Not much help for eclipse users. I have tried the library multidex and pro guard methods. No difference in error. Thanks though.

Comment: Maybe it's time to change to android studio? Because support for eclipse is ending. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Comment: I do feel the same and that exactly is my next move to convert my project into Android studio gradle source but my company has instructed to use eclipse maybe because of other senior developers so I would still look for more answers. Also to add to your previous comment, I had imported the multidex library project from extras folder and used it as a library for my eclipse project and also tried to use just the jar in my project. Both ways I received the same error. Enabling proguard is simpler with eclipse but doesn't help me.

Comment: Just move on to Android Studio as Google will no longer support Android SDK plugin for Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue recently in eclipse. This happens because your project contains too many classes including all the library classes too. I have fixed this issue by using proguard to compress the build file. This is very helpful as it automatically shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code.
Learn about proguarding here: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html
* Remember proguarding gives too many warnings, must use it carefully.

or 
You can also go with the link :

https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/

Comment: I have moved on with Android studio and fixed the issue. Thanks anyways. Please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359811/css-styles-in-android-rich-text-editor-not-working if you have time. I will mark your answer as correct for now.

Comment: sure i’ll try my best to help :)